# How do I add hidden form fields based on which checkbox is selected with javascript?

Tags: javascript, forms, hidden, field, checkbox

I want to write hidden inputs to the form based on which checkboxes are selected.  In my example im not getting errors but it still wont pass the hidden fields-(edited)

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
<div id="test"></div>
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart">
<input type="hidden" name="upload" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="youremail@mail.com">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="US">
<input type="checkbox" id="chkbox1" name="camp1" value="a">
<input type="checkbox" id="chkbox2" name="camp2" value="b">
<input type="submit" value="PayPal">
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
var element = document.getElementById('test');
if(element != null && element.checked) {

var newElement = document.createElement('input');
newElement.type = "hidden";
newElement.name = "item_name_1";
newElement.value = "MyItem #1";

document.getElementById('chkbox1').appendChild(newElement);

var newElement2 = document.createElement('input');
newElement2.type = "hidden";
newElement2.name = "amount_1";
newElement2.value = "7.00";

document.getElementById('test').appendChild(newElement2);
}
```

Theoretically this should work, but it's got me stumped.  If anyone can offer some advice it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Not completely related but, make sure you have some kind of server side validation on those prices you are inserting

Comment: This only happens one time, whenever you are running the script - if you want to add/remove these fields as the checkboxes are toggled, you'll need to add a handler for the checked events on each checkbox. It would probably be easiest, however, to have the fields there either way and decide what to do based on the checkbox selections on the backend.

Comment: Where are you putting that js code? You should make a function to trigger it in the `onclick` event of the checkboxes, plus, are those hidden inputs really necessary? Can't you just put the hidden inputs' values in the checkboxes' values instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, never use `document.write` while in the context of a webpage. That's bad practice. If you want to dynamically add an element with pure javascript, you would simply create a new element:

```
var newElement = document.createElement('input');
newElement.type = "hidden";
newElement.name = "something";
newElement.value = "someValue";

document.getElemenytById('somecontainer').appendChild(newElement);
```

Secondly, the error means that the `document.getElementById` call for one of your statements did not find the specified element. You need to be null checking the results:

```
var element = document.getElementById('chkbox1');

if(element != null && element.checked)
   // Do Stuff
```

Now, without knowing the placement of where your script is, and where this form is in your page, you could suffering from the loading placement. If your script runs before the HTML is loaded, you wont find the elements.